# Add INNER JOIN on Subquery

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Given two tables, nf_users and nf_wr_year, and the following query, how can I add an inner join to the nf_users table in order to select additional columns?

```
SELECT 
    points, 
    played, 
    wins 
FROM (
    SELECT
        p.*,
        @i:=@i + 1 rank,
        @match:=IF(p.points = 528, @i, @match)
    FROM
        nf_wr_year p,
        (SELECT @i:=0, @match:=0) vars
    ORDER BY p.points
) t
WHERE @match >= rank - 2 
    AND @match <= rank + 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the join right after the reference to nf_wr_year:

```
SELECT u.[additional-columns-you-want]
...
FROM
    nf_wr_year p
    join nf_users u
        on u.[something] = p.[something],
    (SELECT @i:=0, @match:=0) vars
ORDER BY p.points
...
```

Make sure you don't have any duplicate column names in the *t* select, e.g. the one you're using to join, commonly via `SELECT p.*, u.*`...